# I want calendar to appear when pressed on my date textfield and the user should be able to select date from that calendar

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<div class="cont-7"><p class="para-2"><span class="font-2">Date</span></p></div>
```

The above is the code for label.

```
 <input id="date"type="text" name="text" class="input">
```

This is the code for textfield for entering date, i want a calendar to appear when i press this text field ...like a date picker.

Comment: You should look at [this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: If you can use html5, modern browsers will give you their default calendar when you use `<input type="date">` or datetime or datetime-local. Else you'll need one fo the plugins/libraries suggested.

Comment: *"Like a date picker"*. Have you looked for date pickers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 browsers have built-in support for date pickers. To do what you are asking you only need to change the type of your input field to date. Like this:

```
 <input id="date"type="date" name="text" class="input">
```